# Windows 10 Unable to Install Pip due to SSL Certificate Error

Tags: python, windows, pip, windows-10

I'm currently working with someone on a Windows 10 that is unable to install Pip for Python on their machine due to an SSL Certificate Error.

We run this command successfully through the command prompt, and we do see the `get-pip.py` on the machine after running it.

`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`

When we try to run the file with `python get-pip.py` we get a bunch of errors regarding SSL Certificate. It appears that something may be blocking the connection, but we're unsure how to proceed. It seems that all the answers we're finding are regarding `pip` unable to install other packages.

Does anyone have an idea what may be preventing us from installing `pip` successfully on Windows 10?

Comment: I'd use your favorite network traffic analysis tool (say wireshark or fiddler) to see what certificate is used and what HTTP calls are made.

Comment: Could you show the error Codes?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why there is an issue on your certificates, but all python 3 installations for Windows include pip by default, you just need to call it this way:
`python -m pip`